# Electron .ipcRenderer fires twice

Tags: electron

I'm creating (for the first time) a small Mac only app using Electron.
I am trying to use ipcRenderer to communicate between my app menu and the content in the main BrowserWindow.

I have the menu set up as follows to send the message 'select-active':

```
const {Menu} = require('electron')
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

const template = [
{
label: 'Fonts',
submenu: [
    {
        label: 'Select All Acitve Fonts',
        accelerator: 'Command+A',
        click (item, focusedWindow) { if(focusedWindow) focusedWindow.webContents.send('select-active') }
    },...
```

which I am then receiving as follows:

```
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

ipcRenderer.on('select-active', function () {
    console.log('SELECTED');
})
```

The problem I have is that every time the menu command is selected the message is logged twice in the console. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How about using .once instead

```
ipcRenderer.once('select-active', function () {
console.log('SELECTED');
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to `ipcRenderer.on` after React component rerendering (React calls your function every time it needs to get rendered version of it). Try to define the `ipcRenderer.on` event handler outside of React component function.

```
function yourFunction(){
    return(){}
}

export default yourFunction;
    
ipcRenderer.send();
```

Place your `ipcRenderer.send();` under the `export default yourFunction;`
It`s works for me!